Unbounded diameter for the blow up on Ricci Flow
Let $(M,g_0)$ be a compact n-dimensional Riemannian Manifold. Suppose that $g(t)$ is an smooth solution to the Ricci flow $\partial_tg(t)=-2Rc(g_t)$ on a maximal time interval $[0,T)$ of existence, where $T$ is finite. It is known that this implies that the curvature explodes as $t\rightarrow T$. In order to study the singularities, one takes an increasing sequence of times $t_i\rightarrow T$ and defines $M_i:=\max_{(x,t)\in M\times [0,t_i]}|R|(x,t)$, and consider the new metrics $g_i(t)=M_ig(t_i+tM_i^{-1})$, which are defined on $[-t_iM_i,M_i(T-t_i)]$. From the theory, one concludes that these new solutions of the Ricci Flow has bounded geometry on an interval the form $(a,b)$, where $0\in (a,b)$. By Perelman non-collapsing theorem, one can take a subsequence on pointed solutions of the Ricci flow $(M,g_i(t),p_i)$ that converges to a pointed solutions of the Ricci flow.
Here is my question: it is easy to see that the Gromov-Cheeger convergence implies Hausdorff convergence of the metric spaces $(M,g_i(0),p_i)$, where $g_i(0)=M_ig(t_i)$. Since our manifold is compact, the limit manifold is compact, and the diffeomorphisms that makes the convergence can be taken to be defined on all $M$. This implies that the diameter of the metrics $g_i(0)$ converges to the diameter of the limit manifold, which we know is compact. However, $Diam(M,g_i(0))=M_i^{1/2}Diam(M,g(t_i))$, and the sequence $M_i\rightarrow$ infinite.
Clearly, something about my reasoning must be wrong, and I will like to know where is my error.

The limit is not compact. The Cheeger-Gromov convergence theorem says that if the diameter is uniformly bounded, then the limit is compact. Here, as you show, the sequence of diameters is unbounded. In that case, you get only pointed convergence on compact subsets. But the limiting manifold need not be compact.
